# Vicidial SIP Trunk with Twilio

Tags: asterisk, twilio

I need a step by step guide on configuring [Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking) on my Vicidial Server. I've been working it out for days now. Still can't make an outbound call. My account on twilio is still a trial account. thank you guys. :(

Comment: Twilio have such guide in their doc. Also twilio offer commercial support. Please note, when you posting on SO you should show attempt of understand yourself. You should not request guide.

Comment: sorry about that arheops, this is really my last resort. I already followed their guide but calls are still can't go through

Answer (score 6):

From vicidial admin panel, go to Admin >> Carriers
Add a new carrier named "myname" 
**Replace "myname" with whatever you like but keep it consistent throughout the config. Anywhere you see "myname" replace it with the same value.

In the account entry section use this template:

Account Entry:

```
[myname]
type=peer
secret=mypassword ;if you created a Credentials list in Twilio the password goes here
username=myuser ;the Credentials username goes here
host=mytrunkname.pstn.twilio.com ;in Twilio this is your Termination SIP URI that you created under Elastic SIP Trunk settings
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
insecure=port,invite
fromuser=+18005551234 ;the phone number associated with your trunk goes here
fromdomain=mytrunkname.pstn.twilio.com
```

Global String: `DIAL9TRUNK = SIP/myname`

Dialplan Entry:

```
exten => _91NXXNXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
exten => _91NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(${DIAL9TRUNK}/+1${EXTEN:2},,To)
exten => _91NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup

exten => _9NXXNXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
exten => _9NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(${DIAL9TRUNK}/+1${EXTEN:1},,tTo)
exten => _9NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup
```

That should activate outbound calling prefixed with the number 9.  Meaning, dial 9 and then the number you want to dial as usual.  You might want to remove all of my comments in the settings just to be safe.  If you need any more help post back with your current config and I'll try to respond quickly.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello James, Thank you for this but it's giving me the same thing, here's a CLI output

Comment: -- Executing [918668667509@default:2] Dial("SIP/1111-00000008", "SIP/twiliosip/+18668667509,,To") in new stack
[Aug  5 19:03:31]   == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[Aug  5 19:03:31]     -- Called SIP/twiliosip/+18668667509
[Aug  5 19:03:31] WARNING[1390]: chan_sip.c:21134 handle_response_invite: Received response: "Forbidden" from '"1111" <sip:+18329002975@flingstest.pstn.twilio.com>;tag=as310679c8'
[Aug  5 19:03:31]   == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
[Aug  5 19:03:31]     -- Executing [918668667509@default:3] Hangup("SIP/1111-00000008", "") in new stack

Comment: add to trunk settings insecure=port,invite

Comment: also can suggest u enable debug and see reason why it declining. if you really added trunk correctly,have be no issues.

Comment: Your dialplan looks fine but you're being rejected at twilio... double check your username/pass and verify your IP address is attached to the trunk in twilio settings.

Comment: Hello James and Arheops, Twilio's outbound calls are now working on my system, Thanks to the two of you. I appreciate it. The problem was actually on my caller id which was incorrect that is why twilio's dropping our calls. Thanks again guys !

Comment: Glad we could help.  Which setting for caller ID was the culprit?  There are several places to input that value and I spoof CID all the time without any trouble.  Curious to know where it causes conflict for you?

Comment: As a side note: Twilio also has a pretty decent Debugger, which shows when it notices problems with calls. As I have found out lately. Your calls would also have showed up there.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is several years old, and I get emails asking how to add Twilio to Vicidial quite frequently. The problem is almost always with how you configure your Twilio account. I have to admit I have found the process fairly painful.

You going to need a unique trunk name for Twilio. I recommend you head to [random.org](https://www.random.org/passwords/?num=6&len=12&format=html&rnd=new) and just use a random string. Copy one and paste it into a note.

1. You need to use a Twilio product called "Elastic SIP Trunking". Here's what you fill in when you create your new Twilio trunk:

- **Trunk Name:** Vicidial
- **Call Recording:** No
- **Secure Trunking:** Disabled
- **Termination URI:** [that random string from random.org].pstn.twilio.com
- **IP Access Control Lists:** (add every public IP address of your Vicidial cluster that needs to dial)
- **Credential Lists:** (here's what people tend to mess up in my experience; make sure these are set with both username and password - I'd copy and past them into a note for reference when trunking Vicidial)
- **Origination SIP URI:** (add the public IP address of one server of your Vicidial cluster; I tend you pick the server that's set as the voicemail server)
- **Priority:** 10
- **Weight:** 10

3. Log into your Administration interface of your Vicidial system and head to Carriers (Administration → Admin → Carriers)
4. Click "Add A New Carrier". It's in the grey bar across the top.

- **Carrier ID:** Twilio
- **Carrier Name:** Elastic SIP Trunk
- **Carrier Description:** (I leave that blank)
- **Registration String:** (leave that blank)
- **Account Entry:**

  [twilio]
  disallow=all
  allow=ulaw
  type=friend
  secret=(password you created in "Credential Lists")
  username=(user name you created in "Credential Lists")
  host=(the value used in "Termination URI", e.g. wkR9PaMPvk9h.pstn.twilio.com)
  dtmfmode=rfc2833
  context=trunk-inbound
- **Globals String:**

  TWILIO = SIP/twilio
- **Dialplan Entry:**

  exten => _91XXXNXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
  exten => _91XXXNXXXXXX,2,Dial(${TWILIO}/${EXTEN:1},,To)
  exten => _91XXXNXXXXXX,3,Hangup

  exten => _9XXXNXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
  exten => _9XXXNXXXXXX,2,Dial(${TWILIO}/1${EXTEN:1},,To)
  exten => _9XXXNXXXXXX,3,Hangup

  exten => _1XXXNXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
  exten => _1XXXNXXXXXX,2,Dial(${TWILIO}/${EXTEN},,To)
  exten => _1XXXNXXXXXX,3,Hangup

  exten => _XXXNXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
  exten => _XXXNXXXXXX,2,Dial(${TWILIO}/1${EXTEN},,To)
  exten => _XXXNXXXXXX,3,Hangup

Submit and ensure the carrier is saved as Active "Y" (you'll have to submit a second time). Wait a minute or two and you should be able to send calls to Twilio. If there's a problem, double and triple check your outbound Caller ID setting as Twilio will block calls if that's not set up *perfectly*.