# Cannot get Vicidial to work with Twilio's elastic SIP trunk

Tags: twilio

I'm experiencing a problem and have tried everything to get my Vicidial to work with the Twilio elastic SIP. Followed the instructions provided in an earlier post found here [Vicidial SIP Trunk with Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821575/vicidial-sip-trunk-with-twilio) hoping to get a solution but were using a UK dial plan so made some adjustments to the dial plan (show below)! Still can't seem to get things moving, It's probably a minor mistake, then again its my first time configuring a Vicidial server so please excuse my lack of competence.

Using the following dial plan configuring the carrier as above with our twilio account info ect;

```
exten => _44XXXXXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
exten => _44XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(${SIPtrunk}/+1${EXTEN:1},,tTo)
exten => _44XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup

exten => _44XXXXXXXXXX,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
exten => _44XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(${SIPtrunk}/+1${EXTEN:2},,To)
exten => _44XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup`
```

Then on initiation of a call were getting the following error!

```
handle_response_invite: Received response: "Forbidden" from '"V4271409150000177996" ;
  tag=as649499a8' [Apr 27 14:09:16] == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)

handle_response_invite: Received response: "Forbidden" from '"V4271409150000177996
```

Now we have checked all the settings in the carrier and all seem to be fine, when we check " sip show peers" we have a connection to twilio just no call initiation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Twilio is responding that you are not authorized to send calls.

Before you send any calls you need to authorize, this means you need to have in your case, {SIPtrunk} entry to be properly configured and have correct context.

This is called Account entry under carriers in vicidial and you have not provided that information here. make sure to hide account data if you do post it

Twilio may also have registration or IP based authorization.You need to know which on you activated

You must correctly authorized with your sip provider before calls could be processed.